# flutter video_player add but showing this error how to fix this?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

flutter video_player add but showing this error how to fix this?

`[Fatal Error] core-1.7.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] core-1.7.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] core-1.7.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform exoplayer-hls-2.18.7.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.18.7) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5016e3f59346f2292b0dc921611e9485\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-hls-2.18.7.
> > C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\34e4c3eb0106e01f66c387668dca5596\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-dash-2.18.7\AndroidManifest.xml
> Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5016e3f59346f2292b0dc921611e9485\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-hls-2.18.7.
> > C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5016e3f59346f2292b0dc921611e9485\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-hls-2.18.7\AndroidManifest.xml
> Failed to transform exoplayer-dash-2.18.7.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.18.7) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\34e4c3eb0106e01f66c387668dca5596\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-dash-2.18.7.
> > C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\34e4c3eb0106e01f66c387668dca5596\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-dash-2.18.7\AndroidManifest.xml
> Failed to transform exoplayer-core-2.18.7.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.7) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\dd54c622e54c5891f3b185aa1eb39281\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-core-2.18.7.
> > C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\dd54c622e54c5891f3b185aa1eb39281\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-core-2.18.7\AndroidManifest.xml
> Failed to transform exoplayer-extractor-2.18.7.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-extractor:2.18.7) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3ca6e7f47e5729e947476659e9e8c08c\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-extractor-2.18.7.
> > C:\Users\lajee.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3ca6e7f47e5729e947476659e9e8c08c\transformed\jetified-exoplayer-extractor-2.18.7\AndroidManifest.xml

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

add video in flutter project`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.